# Presence of form in html makes css transition occur on load in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Consider this simple html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><form></form>                      
        </div><br>

        <div>some text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The test.css file contains:

```css
div {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 6s ease;
  transition: background-color 6s ease;
  background-color: red;
}
div:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

On a page load or refresh in Chrome you can see a transition from grey to red. If you remove the form element, the div starts off red as expected. How can I fix this without javascript/jquery?

Edit: Do not use jsfiddle or codepen or anything like that. The issue is on the page load. These are not full page loads.

Comment: you want transition to occur on hover?

Comment: That's right and that is what the code does, but a transition is also occurring on page load in Chrome if the form element is present. I don't want that to happen. It looks awful.

Comment: add transition in div:hover

Comment: I don't see any gray block, why would it be any gray block as there is no background:gray in your css ?

Comment: Sorry not a gray block just the color of the page. You can clearly see it transition from the browser's default color to red on page-load in Chrome when the form element is present. When the form element isn't present the page loads with the div red to start with

Comment: No I don't see any of that, maybe a Chrome bug, try updating or reinstalling

Comment: No dice. I've changed the code above to a 6 second transition so that on-load or on-refresh its more apparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out this is a Chrome bug:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167083

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/BYh55/)**

Add transition in div:hover if you want transition to take place on hover.

```
div {
    background-color: red;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/BYh55/1/)**

This will help

css

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now when my mouse leaves the div, it doesn't transition on the way out. To try solve this if I add

    div:not(:hover) {
        background-color: red;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    }

I get the same problem with it transitioning on page load in Chrome

Comment: Your second example has the problem of the transition occuring on page load in Chrome when the form tag is present

Comment: @MatthewHolmes both the examples working fine, no transition occurs on page load in chrome.

Comment: @ZahidKhan I second you!

Comment: Yes it looks fine on CodePen, but that is not a normal page load.

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://codepen.io/mouhammed/pen/Hwina

You can use this for on hover and when mouse leave :

```
div {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Still has the problem of the transition occuring from the default color to red, on page load when the form tag is present.

Comment: Witch browser are you using ? Check if you've another background definition in your css !

Comment: It works fine in my browser with the same version 36.0.1985.125. Do you have another code on you css ?

Comment: Are you guys looking on CodePen? It works fine there, but that is not a normal page load.

Comment: I've also launched th html code from my file system. It works just fine.